# Parse JSON object with string and value only

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, dictionary

I have problem when trying to parse with minimum value to map in Android.

There some sample JSON format with more information ex:

```
[{id:"1", name:"sql"},{id:"2",name:"android"},{id:"3",name:"mvc"}]
```

This that example most common to use and easy to use just use `getString("id")` or `getValue("name")`.

But how do I parse to map using this JSON format with just only string and value minimum format to java map collection using looping. And because the string json will always different one with another. ex:

```
{"1":"sql", "2":"android", "3":"mvc"}
```

Thank

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need to get a list of all the keys, loop over them and add them to your map as shown in the example below:

```
    String s = "{menu:{\"1\":\"sql\", \"2\":\"android\", \"3\":\"mvc\"}}";
    JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONObject  menu = jObject.getJSONObject("menu");

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Iterator iter = menu.keys();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        String value = menu.getString(key);
        map.put(key,value);
    }
```

Comment: What's the import for `JSONObject`?

Comment: @8bitjunkie, It's org.json:json

Answer (score 11):

My **pseudocode** example will be as follows:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = "[{id:\"1\", name:\"sql\"},{id:\"2\",name:\"android\"},{id:\"3\",name:\"mvc\"}]";
JSON newJson = new JSON();

for (each json in jsonArray) {
    String id = json.get("id");
    String name = json.get("name");

    newJson.put(id, name);
}

return newJson;
```

Comment: Probably because they're asking about a json object not json array.

Comment: @PixMach the String the OP provided is a JSON array. It starts with a `[` and ends with a `]`.