# JSON Parsing in Android for Strings Without Label

Tags: java, android, json

I have problem when trying to parse this JSON.

```
{
    "bakso-roso-n'deso__-6.19_106.77":
    {"Latitude":"-6.185488","Longitude":"106.77366","Distance":"90.89210930799594"},
    "print-point-duri-kepa__-6.19_106.77":
    {"Latitude":"-6.18599544813468","Longitude":"106.772603988647","Distance":"118.9849339548274"},
    "apartment-menara-kebun-jeruk__-6.19_106.78":
    {"Latitude":"-6.18530376709007","Longitude":"106.775222279179","Distance":"247.8816947606767"},
    "ranch-market---pesanggrahan__-6.19_106.77":
    {"Latitude":"-6.18761306472002","Longitude":"106.77343661177","Distance":"294.4255786871916"}
}
```

The problem is how I get "bakso-roso-n'deso__-6.19_106.77" as string. It doesn't have any tag.

Thank you.

Now regular way to handle Json is like this:

```
String jstring = "{\"menu\": {\"id\": \"file\", \"value\": \"File\",\"popup\": {\"menuitem\": [{\"value\": \"New\", \"onclick\": \"CreateNewDoc()\"},{\"value\": \"Open\", \"onclick\": \"OpenDoc()\"},{\"value\": \"Close\", \"onclick\": \"CloseDoc()\"}]}}}";
try
{
    jObject = new JSONObject(jstring);
```

How would I do that for this type of json? What should jstring be?

Basically I want to turn these json string into some dictionary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407532/parse-json-object-with-string-and-value-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your `"bakso-roso-n'deso__-6.19_106.77"` is the tag (key ?) itself..

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(YOUR_RESPONSE_STRING);
Iterator<String> myIter = jsonObject.keys();
while(myIter.hasNext()){
  //here you can get all keys
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> plz check this string this is not a valid json String..

```
 String jstring = "{\"menu\": {\"id\": \"file\", \"value\": \"File\",\"popup\": {\"menuitem\": [{\"value\": \"New\", \"onclick\": \"CreateNewDoc()\"},{\"value\": \"Open\", \"onclick\": \"OpenDoc()\"},{\"value\": \"Close\", \"onclick\": \"CloseDoc()\"}]}}}";
```

> check the json is valid or not http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the iterator over keys using jObject.keys();

as per your code ....

```
String jstring = "{\"menu\": {\"id\": \"file\", \"value\": \"File\",\"popup\": {\"menuitem\": [{\"value\": \"New\", \"onclick\": \"CreateNewDoc()\"},{\"value\": \"Open\", \"onclick\": \"OpenDoc()\"},{\"value\": \"Close\", \"onclick\": \"CloseDoc()\"}]}}}";


  try
      {
         jObject = new JSONObject(jstring);
         Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
         Iterator iter = jObject.keys();

         while(iter.hasNext()){
            String key = (String)iter.next();
            String value = menu.getString(key);
            map.put(key,value);
        }
    } catch(exception e){}
```

[Parse JSON object with string and value only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407532/parse-json-object-with-string-and-value-only)