# how to parse unusual json

Tags: java, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse JSON object with string and value only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407532/parse-json-object-with-string-and-value-only)
>   [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

How can I parse such json?

```
"prices":{"2":"800.0", "8":"580.0", "5":"657.0"}
```

Usually I do it in this way:

```
object.getInt("id")
```

But now I don't know previously what int I get. In example there are 2,8,5, but they can be another..

Thanks in advance.

[Here is answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407532/parse-json-object-with-string-and-value-only)

Comment: not sure about the phrase "what int I get". Are you trying to get the integer value from the json string? If yes, Why dont you just use object.getString() and then cast the type to int?

Comment: @ThaiTran I need to parse this: "2":"800.0", "8":"580.0", "5":"657.0" ! The first number is id, the second - value. The ids are always different! The only way I know is cast JSONObject to string and parse string but maybe there is better way.

Answer (score 0):

You need a JSON library for Java.