# keys() is undefined for the type JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Why do i get this error when i'm trying to get the keys of ***JSONObject*** ?
its clearly in the [API](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

And I'm importing the correct library :

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

I saw an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407532/parse-json-object-with-string-and-value-only) of usage and it is working for them .
this is part of my code where i get the error :

```
JSONArray pObject = (JSONArray) srcClaims.get(i);
for (int j=0; j < pObject.size() ; j++) {
    JSONObject mainsnak = (JSONObject) pObject.get(j);
    mainsnak.keys();
```

And i forgot to mention the libray i'm using ***json-simple-1.1.1.jar***.

Comment: we need some more, explain clearly,

Comment: Please update your code.

Comment: Is the title of your question the *exact* error message? Are you sure you don't have another class called `JSONObject`? If you hover over `JSONObject` in the IDE, what fully-qualified name does it show?

Comment: You're refering to a documentation of another library. It has defined JSONObject in the package `org.json.JSONObject`, you're importing from `org.json.simple`.

Comment: yes the exact message, and when i hover the JSONObject i get org.json.simple.JSONObject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at the documentation for the wrong library. In json-simple, [`JSONObject`](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONObject.java) extends `HashMap`, so you should use `keySet()`... or change to use the json.org library instead.

Comment: thanks i downloaded the org.json-20120521.jar  and it works